# Reinforcement Learning with dynamic action space

Tags: pytorch, game-development, reinforcement-learning

I am looking to developing a RL agent to play my two player card game. To train this agent I have a node-socket server that runs the game logic where two players(agents) can connect and play against each other. The server receives moves and retains the state.

### The environment

The game starts by dealing each player four cards and a starting card. According to the game rules, a player may lose a set of cards to the waste stack or they may pick a card from the closed deck. Furthermore, there are cards that may force special actions from the opponent such as picking three cards. The goal of the game is to lose all cards to the waste stack, losing the a winning card last.

The env space:

- agent_hand
- top_card
- num_of_cards_on_the_deck
- player_turn

Since it is a 54 card game, I hot-encoded the hand and the top card as (1*54) tensors and stack them.

### action space

The game server generates all the possible moves for a player, considering the player's hand, the top card and any special actions by the opponent. The number of actions available varies for the agent, making it difficult to have a stable output. Furthermore this actions are always different for every state. How do I tackle this problem?

I tried to limit a possible action space to a maximum 32 actions per state like this:

```
   def network(self):
        self.f1 = nn.Linear(880, self.first_layer)
        self.f2 = nn.Linear(self.first_layer, self.second_layer)
        self.f3 = nn.Linear(self.second_layer, self.third_layer)
        self.f4 = nn.Linear(self.third_layer, 32)
```

I ran into problems since the actions themselves are different.